# Swift: conforming to protocol using extension and composition pattern

Tags: swift, design-patterns, protocols, composition, composite

On slide 62 in this PDF: [Some Columbia College Presentation](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~aho/cs6998/Lectures/14-09-22_Roark_Swift.pdf) it says that one of the ideas behind Swift and its extensions was to conform to protocols using the composition pattern.

Now I understand the syntax for extensions in Swift

```
//example from Apple:
extension SomeType: SomeProtocol, AnotherProtocol {
// implementations of not yet provided functions and properties of SomeType go here
}
```

But what does the composition pattern have to do with it? The guy did mean the *composite* pattern described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), right? Can someone please provide a minimal example how it is used?

Comment: the "composition pattern" in your example means, that SomeType conforms to protocols SomeProtocol and AnotherProtocol. Don't look for some magic or wizard behind the scene ... Try to check apple docs and try to use the terminology they are using. How to use protocol based programming pattern is written there very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Composition` refers to "implementing" interfaces, in Swift called conforming to `protocols`.

On the other side of the fence is `Inheritance` where you extend classes.

The main problem here is that you can only extend one class but conform to as many interfaces as you wish (at least in Swift). Therefore if your class wants to be the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` you can only achieve that with composition.

Interfaces/Protocols leave a lot more open to the developer in opposition to what classes can you. Protocols only *define* functions and methods - and in Swift properties, which have some function-like functionality themselves. Classes on the other hand can contain variables, constants etc. And they can implement some of them already - something that interfaces mostly cannot do.

Comment: Very confusing terminology. it is like Apple is using different terms for the same stuff that is known under different name everywhere else on purpose. The iOS UX guide is full of that stuff too, for example the "three themes" that are basically flat design